# Create a topic with authorization rule using azure-messaging-servicebus

Tags: java, azure, groovy, azureservicebus

I'm trying to create a topic using ServiceBusAdministrationClient connected through a namespace's root manage access key
(com.azure:azure-messaging-servicebus:7.8.0)

```
def createOptions = new CreateTopicOptions()
def authRule = new SharedAccessAuthorizationRule(authRuleName, [AccessRights.SEND, AccessRights.LISTEN])
createOptions.authorizationRules.add(authRule)
def topicProps = administrationClient.createTopic(topicName, createOptions)
```

but there are no AuthorizationRules associated with the topic.
I did the same thing when creating a queue and it worked.
Any ideas what I might be missing?

Answer (score 0):

For the authorization rule, you need to use [Azure Resource Management library](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/azure-sdk/introducing-mgmt-for-java/)
Below is a sample to create an authorization rule

```
final AzureProfile profile = new AzureProfile(AzureEnvironment.AZURE);

final TokenCredential credential =
    new DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder()
        .authorityHost(profile.getEnvironment().getActiveDirectoryEndpoint())
        .build();

var azureResourceManager =
    AzureResourceManager.configure()
        .withLogLevel(HttpLogDetailLevel.BODY_AND_HEADERS)
        .authenticate(credential, profile)
        .withSubscription("subscription");

ServiceBusManager manager = azureResourceManager.serviceBusNamespaces().manager();

SBAuthorizationRuleInner authorizationRule =
    manager
        .serviceClient()
        .getTopics()
        .createOrUpdateAuthorizationRule(
            "resourceGroupName", "namespaceName", "topicName", "authorizationRuleName");
```

Comment: Yes, in the end I used this library because I could not find why azure-messaging-servicebus is not working as I assumed. Maybe someone can still figure it out.

Comment: Agree, it's confusing. I think the Azure team should move all management-related stuff to the resource management library. BTW, if you had already figured it out then please post the answer, it would have helped others. I spent countless hours :-)

Answer (score -1):

There are two different ways to do the required thing.

1. Azure Active Directory (ADD) - [AuthorizationRules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-authentication-and-authorization#azure-active-directory)
2. Shared Access Signature. [Shared access signature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-authentication-and-authorization#shared-access-signature)

There is a professional documentation to the series of steps to be followe.

[Tutorial: Update inventory using Azure portal and topics/subscriptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-tutorial-topics-subscriptions-portal)